# Bing API for Search - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bing, bing-api

Does anyone know of a gem for the new Bing API? It seems like neither rbing nor binger work anymore due to the new Azure Marketplace release.

Microsoft's example is in PHP.